# How is the coordinate system working in URDF

Tags: urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner and I can't seem to understand as I was going through some examples of URDF that how the Coordinate system is working here though, I am sure it's working normally but it's not making any sense to me.
Below is an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<robot name = "my_first">

 <link name="base_link">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
     <cylinder length = "0.01" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy = "0 0 0" xyz = "0 0 0"/>
      <material name = "yellow">
        <color rgba= "1 1 0 1"/>
      <material/>
     </visual>
    </link>

    <joint name = "pan_joint" type = "revolute">
     <parent link = "base_link"/> 
     <child link = "pan_link"/>
     <origin xyz = "0 0 0.1"/>
     <axis xyz = "0 0 1"/>
    <joint/>
 
   <link name = "pan_link">
    <visual>
     <geometry>
     <cylinder length = "0.4" radius = "0.04"/>
     <geometry/>
     <origin rpy = " 0 0 0" xyz = " 0 0 0.09"/>
      <material name="red"> 
        <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/> 
      <material/>
    <visual/>
   <link/>


    <joint name="tilt_joint" type="revolute">  
       <parent link="pan_link"/>  
        <child link="tilt_link"/>  
         <origin xyz="0 0 0.2"/>  
         <axis xyz="0 1 0" /> 
    </joint>


 <link name="tilt_link">    
   <visual>      
    <geometry> 
      <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.04"/>   
    </geometry>     
 <origin rpy="0 1.5 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="green">
        <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
 </robot>
```

How are the Pan_link's and tilt's xyz is calculated ?
Whats the differnce b/w origin rpy and xyz ?
please help me out here

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284924/how-is-the-coordinate-system-working-in-urdf/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend reading through
http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/model,
http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint,
and http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link
if you have not already.

---

joints represent connections between link / reference frames:

- origin rpy attribute: "Represents the rotation around fixed axis: first roll around x, then pitch around y and finally yaw around z. All angles are specified in radians" (Tait-Bryan xyz extrinsic rotations) relative to the parent link's reference frame (effectively the parent joint).
- origin xyz attribute: Represents the x, y, z translation relative to the parent link's reference frame (effectively the parent joint).

links represent rigid bodies:

- origin rpy attribute: "Represents the rotation around fixed axis: first roll around x, then pitch around y and finally yaw around z. All angles are specified in radians" (Tait-Bryan xyz extrinsic rotations) relative to the parent joint.
- origin xyz attribute: Represents the x, y, z translation relative to the parent joint.

---

If you want to be confused: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait-Bryan_angles

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-09**:
Also you can watch this guy blather on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9WHxOpAUns

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-03-09**:
thanks a lot, I did not the read the above links, I will read it and see it though.

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-03-09**:
That video helped me when I started learning about urdf/ros!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:\

> you can watch this guy blather on

@David Lu: +1 :)

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-09**:
Who has two thumbs and can blather on about URDF? http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/wp-content/uploads/brainlitter/2013/02/ThisGuy_thumb.gif